# literal eval with unicode as output or alternative

Tags: python, json, unicode

So if I understand it correctly `literal_eval()` can parse unicode but the output is a string (encoded in UTF-8). Is there a way to prevent this or do you know a way I can achieve this?

With JSON I have the problem that it won't read data type with unnecessary commas at the end, for example `{"key":"value",}` won't work (which works with `literal_eval()`).

Maybe YAML would work but I am a little bit afraid of security problems as you can create there functions as well.

Do you think an alternative would be taking the `literal_eval()` code and rewrite it?

Comment: So, just to get this clear, you want to use `literal_eval` as a _replacement_ for `json.loads`? What if there's a `null` value or similar? Might be easier to just replace `,}` with `}`, provided that those do not occurr within the values.

Comment: `literal_eval` will give you whatever data type the string expression you pass it evaluates to, which can be a string, int, float, whatever has a string representation that can be used to reconstruct it. Unfortunately, JSON and Python's literal representations are not identical so it can't used it in place of `json.load`.

Comment: No I would rather like to use `literal_eval`, but this returns `str` instead of `unicode`. `json.loads` returns `unicode`, but doesn't work with `{"key":"value",}`

Comment: @martineau When I use it `print type(literal_eval("\"§\""))` it returns `<type 'str'>`

Comment: You could write something that took results from `literal_eval` and converted it to unicode (assuming it's known type).

Comment: Where's the JSON data coming from, because with the trailing commas, it's invalid.

Comment: That seems pretty unefficient, doesn't it? As it would first need to use `literal_eval` and then it would need to go through every data structure replacing `str` with `unicode`

Comment: Why do you care what encoding the string object uses internally? Btw, I doubt it uses UTF-8.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, you are right, seems to use `string-escape`, however I need later unicode strings also to get the length of the string

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were doing. Can you go through the literal_eval's result and convert every str to unicode with `unicode(s, 'utf-8')`? Or can you use Python 3, where Unicode is the default, so literal_eval  already works like you want it to? It's one of the main reasons I prefer Python 3.

Comment: No sorry I am using Python 2.7 at the moment. Changing this would be maybe too much work. However I just changed it now so that it decodes the string when it gets it from the data structure `literal_eval` created

Answer (score 0):

1. `ast.literal_eval()` can return Unicode:

   ```
   >>> import ast
   >>> ast.literal_eval(u'u"§"')
   u'\xa7'
   >>> type(_)
   <type 'unicode'>
   ```
2. `{"key":"value",}` is not a valid [JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). The right solution is to find whatever piece of software generates it and fix it. There are [tons of json libraries for different languages](http://json.org/).